# How to run selenium script with latest firefox browser on geckodriver with selenium 2.53.0?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to run automation script with following configurations.

**Configurations :**

- Selenium-java 2.53.0
- Selenium-server 2.53.0
- JRE 7 Firefox 49.0
- geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64

Firefox is opened but not script is not able to enter URL.

[image]

Please refer following error trace :

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
ey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default 
Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1477028214411,"updateDate":1477028214411,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":21905,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"49.0.2","maxVersion":"49.0.2"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}
1478243939636   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
```

**Please let me know If requires more information.**

Answer (score 3):

Selenium 2.53.1 and older doesn't working with FF 4.7 and older.
You need to update Selenium to 3.0.2, download Firefox 47.1 and elder< download Gecko Driver (to run test in FF 47 and elder) and keep calm.

[Selenium changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG)

> ## v3.0.0
>
> IMPORTANT CHANGES
>
> - Firefox is only fully supported at version 47.0.1 or earlier. Support   for later versions of firefox is provided by geckodriver,
>     which is   based on the evolving W3C WebDriver spec, and uses the wire
>     protocol   in that spec, which is liable to change without notice.
> - You may wish to choose an ESR release such as 45.4.0esr or earlier.
> - Firefox 47.0.0 is not supported at all.

Comment: Hi, So it is require to update JRE and selenium version as well.

Comment: For working with FF 47.0.1 or above, you need to update Selenium to 3.0.2. Support for later versions of firefox is provided by geckodriver

Comment: Thank You abhinav and nikita